# QML ListModel file read/write and good practices

Tags: qt, design-patterns, qml

I am just starting to learn QML and I am kinda lost at what should I do when I want to read ListModel from settings.

My dilemma is:

1) If I define the model in C++ code I have no problems loading it (I have done similar stuff loads of times) but I am sacrificing my time to actually write (and later update) model code and then recompile each time I need to do it.

2) My other idea is to read settings file into QList of QVariantMap and create the model in QML file reading this list using javascript. This way I will only need 2 C++ functions, one to read the file section by section and one to write it. But as I said - I am only starting QML programming and not sure if it is sane or discouraged.

Can someone comment on good practices when one needs dynamic QML ListModel?

**UPD**: I seem to need to clarify the question:

Do I even need C++ data model if the stuff is simple enough to read from settings and then parse directly into ListModel via Javascript? Or are there pitfalls I am not aware of that make C++ way the only reasonable choice?

**UPD2** After some mroe researching I am tempted to go with LocalStorage and forgo c++ altogether

Comment: What do you men by `settings`? Are talking about `QSettings` or is that something custom?

Comment: QSettings -> QList<QVariantMap> -> Call function that returns the former from QML -> model.append in a javascript routine

Comment: This way, if I am not falling into some trap I am not aware of, all of the model initialization/structure will be editable without recompiling

Comment: Have you think about to create your own QML type to manage settings? It could seam hard to create but it isn't, and you will have strong typed properties for each setting's field.

Answer (score 1):

Making an existing C++ model editable is quit easy, since you get everything from Qt.

You have the following in .h

```
class MyModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum MyRoles {
        SomeRole = Qt::UserRole,
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role);
```

in .cpp

```
bool MyModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    switch (role) {
    case SomeRole:
        // your writer code
        emit dataChanged(index, index, (QVector<int>(0) << SomeRole));
        return true;
    case SomeOtherRole:
        // ...
        return true;
    default:
        qCritical() << "MyModel.setData: Unknown role:" << role;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now your can use QML internals to perfrom a write.

```
MyModelDelegate {
    Button {
        text: somerole
        onClicked: {
            // this will call setData with the correct row index and SomeRole 
            somerole = "some other value"
        }
    }
}
```

This C++ code is only recompiled when you add new roles, which should not happen very often or your write method changed.

Comment: this is exactly the thing I wanted to avoid. way too much on the c++ side

Comment: Well, if a 1-method wrapper around your C++ write method is too much, I think I cannot help.

Comment: It's is not a method wrapper per se. I would still have to implement a lot of abstract stuff to make model working. Like data(), columns(), rows... etc. No?

Comment: Jap, it is `roleNames()`, `rowCount()`, and `data()` where the first two are trivial. I was assuming you are familiar with read-only list models in C++.

Comment: Trivial, yes, but you said it yourself _the first two_. You seem to not understand the real problem from original post. I could of course implement all this without any problems, but I consider this too much. It is just not as thin as my second approach. I was hoping someone would comment on that. As for me being unfamiliar with read only models - I have never used roleNames, yes, and just didn't bother writing proper names for other functions.

Comment: Well, now I get the point. At the end of the day, it's a question of performance, maintainability and of course taste. Maybe you should look for a JS-only solution instead of best practice ;)